# Grails 3 importFrom in Command Object constraints

Tags: validation, grails

I used to be able keep command objects separate from controllers in `src/groovy` in Grails 2.5.x. Now when trying to import constraints within command objects placed in `src/main/groovy` I get the error `groovy.lang.MissingMethodException`.

My command object is as follows:

```
class ProfileCommand implements Validateable {

    String lastName
    String firstName

    static constraints = {
        importFrom Profile
    }
}
```

I did see the following line in the validation guide for grails 3.1.6

> It is important that the application register the validateable classes with the framework. Simply defining the constraints property is not sufficient.

Where do I go about registering these classes then?

Comment: implements Validateable  is for grails 3  https://github.com/vahidhedayati/grails-wschat-plugin/blob/master/src/main/groovy/grails/plugin/wschat/beans/ConfigBean.groovy  for grails 2 it is @Validateable  https://github.com/vahidhedayati/grails-wschat-plugin/blob/grails2/src/groovy/grails/plugin/wschat/beans/ConfigBean.groovy  - Very important difference there really

Comment: @vahid correct and that is why I followed the docs for grails 3 for my grails 3 app.

Comment: unsure what to say I have it working in grails 3. I know valuation had an issue in grail 3.1 something but 3.1.4+ works again. Take a look at issues resolved under wschat. If you are using older than 3.1.4.